# Can I get Entity Framework to create code for my many-to-many relationship tables?

Tags: entity-framework

Say I have the MSSQL tables A, AB and B, where AB is a simple ManyToMany mapping table containing two columns: Primary key for A and Primary key for B. Entity Framework does not generate a class for AB, only a collection of B in A and of A in B. Sometimes I want to list the contents of AB as is.

Is there any way I can get EF to generate code for the AB ManyToMany-table?

PS I'm using [Rob Halletts Mocking Context Object Generator](http://blogofrab.blogspot.com/2010/08/maintenance-free-mocking-for-unit.html) for code generation. Don't know if this is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The join table is never represented as an entity in your model. But you can list the content of the `AB` join table also without that entity:

```
var joinTableList = (from a in context.As
                     from b in a.Bs
                     select new
                     {
                         AId = a.Id,
                         BId = b.Id
                     })
                    .ToList();
```

You get a list of of anonymous objects. Every object has the `AId` and `BId` as properties. This LINQ query is translated into a very simple SQL query over table `AB` without any joins:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[AId] AS [AId], 
[Extent1].[BId] AS [BId]
FROM [dbo].[ABs] AS [Extent1]
```